# Fetch API results from Wikipedia

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, wikipedia-api

I must write a code which will take info from Wikipedia, and I wrote this:

```
function getInfo() {
    let search = "Teatr Wielki";

    fetch("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?&origin=*&action=opensearch&search=" + search + "&limit=5", {
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
        },
    }).then(response => response.json())
      .then(addInfo)
      .catch (e => requestError(e));

    function addInfo(data) {
        console.log(data);
        const info = data.results[3][1];
        if (info) {
            document.querySelector('#results').innerHTML = info;
        } else {
            document.querySelector('#results').innerHTML = 'Unfortunately, no info was returned for this data.'
        }
    }

    function requestError(e, part) {
        console.log(e);
        document.querySelector('#results').innerHTML = '<br>Oh no! There was an error making a request for this place';
    }
}
```

But this code returns an error:

> TypeError:  Cannot read property '3' of undefined at addInfo.

I tried to used many options, for example: only [0], only [1] - but nothing is working. Maybe some of you know what is wrong in my code?

Comment: Just check the response and you will see the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data returned from the wikipedia (mediawiki) api does not have the `results` key. The response from the server is a single array.

So, to fetch result, in your code, you must supress the `results` key and access directly the data object:

```
const info = data[3][1];
```

Your working code: https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/cq73byu8/

Comment: Hi mrlew! Thanks so much for this info! It works :) Thanks!